# Feed intersection's coordinates to pgfplots' \addplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, intersections

Following examples in the manual and elsewhere, I can use Tikz to mark an intersection on a pgfplots axis and even display the coordinates (see the commented out section in the MWE below), but I would rather use pgfplots' `\addplot` to mark the intersection for styling consistency and easy legend integration. How can I store and recall the intersection's coordinates programmatically to use with the `\addplot`? Try as I might, I can't get `\pgfplotspointgetcoordinates` to work outside the `\path[name intersections...]` command.

In the example below, we have the ordinate (i.e. the fail rate) for the "unranked" data point, but we don't know the abscissa.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=6cm,
    xlabel=Quartile,
    xtick distance=1,
    ylabel=Fail rate (\%),
    every axis plot/.append style={very thick, mark=*},
    cycle list={[samples of colormap=4 of viridis]},
]

\addplot+ [name path=main, forget plot] table [x=quartile, y=rate] {
    quartile rate
    1 4.5
    2 2
    3 1
    4 0.5
};

\def\yextra{1.7}
\path [name path=helperline] (0,\yextra -| current axis.west) -- (0,\yextra -| current axis.east);

% \path [name intersections={of=main and helperline, name=int}] 
%     node [red, circle, fill, minimum size=2pt,
%     pin={
%         \pgfplotspointgetcoordinates{(int-1)}
%         $(\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{
%         \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x}},
%         \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{
%         \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}})$
%     },
% ] (A) at (int-1) {}; % This works, but is not what I want

% \pgfplotspointgetcoordinates{(int-1)} % doesn't work
% \pgfplotspointgetcoordinates{(A)} % doesn't work

% % Below is what I want, but programmatic instead of manual
\addplot+ [mark options={fill=white}, only marks] coordinates {(2.3,1.7)};
\addlegendentry{unranked}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---